# Year not showing up in APA-style citations

Tags: citing, apa-style

I'm writing a paper in LaTeX at the moment. I'm using the \usepackage{apacite}, but for some reason, the years will not show up in my in-text citations. The entry in the References section is fine, however. The entry in the BibTeX file is perfect; I'm reasonably positive that that isn't the problem.

My citation should look like this: (Binney & Tremaine, 2011). However, it just comes up as (Binney & Tremaine, ) and gives me a whole bunch of error messages. Here is my code. I would appreciate any answers.

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm,upref}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}\geometry{margin=2cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{physics}
\providecommand{\e}[1]{\ensuremath{\times 10^{#1}}}

\title{}

\author{}

\date{10/8/2015}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Measures of distance}
    \subsection{Part (a)}
    ... the parsec is now defined as exactly $648,000/\pi$ AU \cite{bintrem}...
\bibliography{biblio}{}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. First, did you run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more? (That's what's need to produce both the formattted bibliogrpaphy and the citation call-outs.) Second, did you check for any error or warning or error message in the ``\jobname.blg` log file?

Answer (score 3):

To quote the documentation of apacite:

> apacite is compatible with hyperref, provided that apacite is loaded
>   *after* hyperref.

So move `\usepackage{apacite}` behind `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

(It would be easier to help you if you had mentioned the exact error text instead simply writing that you get a vage "whole bunch of error messages"